# how to reset viewer to its original size after dashboard is created

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

seems only dashboard content being cleared w/ remove() function, viewer won't automatically be resized, so how to resize viewer (in this case, enlarge width)?

my code snippet as below:

```
$("#dashboard").remove();
```

Answer (score 2):

It's straightforward, just call `viewer.resize();`

ref: https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Viewing/GuiViewer3D/#resize

Comment: thanks Eason, works OK but only partially, after using viewer.resize(), the rendered elements in viewer are in correct location so i can select w/o having to move my mouse a bit to right (dashboard width), but dashboard portion is still displayed in client UI, i tried viewer.refresh() but doesn't work

Comment: well, seems using DOM to adjust layout is OK even though it's kind of "dumb"

Answer (score 1):

You may also need to do viewer.impl.invalidate()

```
viewer.resize();
viewer.impl.invalidate();
```